# How to give a specific output from something selected in dropdown? (winforms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

so I've been developing a program for a while, it's going well.

But one problem I'm having is that, I can't find anything to help this problem.

So, I have a dropdown list, with a few things. When I select something, I want it to give an output of a listed number.
For example,

Option 1 from Dropdown > Outputs number 1

Option 2 from Dropdown > Outputs number 2

Option 5 from Dropdown > Outputs number 5

etc, etc.

Does anyone have an idea on what I could do?

```
protected void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
    switch (selectedIndex)
    {
        case 1:
            MessageBox.Show("1");
            break;
        case 2:
            MessageBox.Show("2");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which framework are you working with? ASP.NET? Winforms?

Comment: You can use switch or if statements;

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to get the selected item's index, with the `SelectedIndex` property:

```
protected void drp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedIndex = drp.SelectedIndex + 1;
}
```

Note I'm adding `+ 1` to the value since the selected item's index strats at `0`.
When the user selects the 1st option, `selectedIndex` will have the value `1`. When the user selects the 2nd option, `selectedIndex` will have the value `2`.

Now you can use this variable to take actions based on its value:

```
protected void drp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedIndex = drp.SelectedIndex + 1;

    switch (selectedIndex)
    {
        case 1:
            // Do Stuff
            break;
        case 2:
            // Do Stuff
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to react at all when I put this in.

Comment: I'm not using HTML, I'm using winforms. Forgot to say earlier.

Comment: Did you register a `SelectedIndexChanged` event on the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

Using switch statements will work.

```
switch (combobox.selectedIndex) //Gets the index of the selected item.
    {
        case 0:
            Console.WriteLine("YOur thing");
            break;
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Default case");
            break;
    }
```